# WordPress plugin for subscription to a beta test program

Tags: wordpress, newsletter

I'm going to release an app for Android and I'm building up a WordPress website to promote it.

I need a plugin to collect email address of interested users and then, once subscribed, it has to send them the link to download the beta app version.

Does anyone know one?